# Is there any way to add multliple quality sources to flowplayer in Angular

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, flowplayer

I am trying to add multiple sources with different qualities like 1080p, 720p etc.. Is there any way to add multiple sources. Thank you in advance

```
flowplayer('#my_player',
      {
        src: '../assets/videos/video_1080p.mp4',
        // title: 'This is just demo',
        ima: {
          ads: [
            { time: 0, adTag: 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/single_ad_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ct%3Dlinear&correlator='},
          ]
        },
      },)


<div id="my_player"></div>
```

Comment: Question doesn't have enough clarity as to what you are trying to do

Comment: I am trying add multiple sources of different qualities. But in the official documentation there is no quality changer to multiple local sources

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `qsel` plugin.

[quality selection Documentation](https://docs.flowplayer.com/plugins/qsel)

```
var player = flowplayer('#container',
  { src  : '//edge.flowplayer.org/bauhaus.m3u8'
  , qsel : {labels:
    [
               // index 1,  default label "800p" will be used, note the comma indicating the next level is the second one
    , "second" // index 2
    , "third"  // index 3
    , false    // index 4, hide fourth level by setting it to false , option will be hidden
    , "fifth"  // index 5
    ,          // index 6 uses default label "200p"
    , false    // index 7, do not show
    , false    // index 8, do not show
    ]}
  })
```

Comment: But my src is not a .m3u8 or part of flowplayer storage

Comment: @voltcorp you can try this method to fix your issue! I just shared the snippet on the website documentation